# MVVM practices: expose viewmodel class inside a control

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel

I've edited the question to make what I want to obtain clearer.
Here's the original question:

*I'm working on a class that inherits from Control which will be used in my View and includes some Dependency Properties.

One of these DPs is an `IEnumerable(Of RfidTag)` and will be bound to an `ObservableCollection(Of RfidTag)` inside the VM.
The class `RfidTag` is defined as public class in the same file where the VM's class resides.*

*The questions are:*

*1. is it a good practice to expose a VM-related class to a Control class?*
*2. is the VM source file a good place for the `RfidTag` class?*

**UPDATE 1**
In my application logic (I think I could say in my Model) there is an event published throught an Eventaggregator. The event's payload is a List of `ModelRfidTag` (that is the model class).
My VM subscribes to this event and I made the `RfidTag` class to wrap my Model class and provides some additional properties related only to the VM.

When the event handler inside the VM is executed, it makes an `ObservableCollection(Of RfidTag)` bindable from the view.
Then in the View I've a bounch of my control instances like that

```
<c:RfidTagPresenter 
TagPosition="1"
Collection="{Binding RfidTagList, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Then in my `RfidTagPresenter` (the class that inherits from Control) I've a DP of type `RfidTag` (called `RfidTagResult`) that returns the object in the OC which has the `Position` property (property available inside the `RfidTag` class) equal to the value set by the `TagPosition` DP.
In this way, the ControlTemplate of the `RfidTagPresenter` can bind its elements to the desired object.

This is the simplification of what I want to make. In the actual application there are some other DPs on which the RfidTagResult selection is performed

**UPDATE 2**
After a bit of research, seem that I can solve one problem with an indexed property that return (in the get method) the object from the collection I want to bind.
However a problem still exist: My control need to have a DP of type of RfidTag so that the relative ControlTemplate can bind to the property declared in the RfidTag class.
So: Is it possible (read: a good practice) to have a DP of a type that is a VM related class?
In other words: Can a custom control know about the class type used by the VM?

Comment: Per definition the ViewModel is an independent class and has nothing to do with the UI. Therefore you should think about solving the situation that you have. You have a class that inherits from Control (which is UI-dependent) in your ViewModel. This, per definition, is a bad practice.

In theory you should always be able to use your viewmodels again, no matter if there is a WPF or a WinForms-Application on top.

Comment: Ty Dominic, but the problem is slightly different: maybe I've not explained well: the rfidtag class was originally made only for the VM to represent an item in a collection. Then I created a control that will be used in the view to represent visually an object. I've created two DPs that are used to specify (via xaml binding) a collection and an integer index. In this way my control can operate on a specified index of a specified collection. So now a VM-related class must be referenced (as data type) inside a control class because my control need to know how the items of the list are made...

Comment: In other words, my control will be usable only in conjunction with this particular VM because one of the DP is an IEnumerable(Of RfidTag), and RfidTag is a class defined in the VM namespace.

Comment: Could you please post how you create your DP ? Can't really see how you declare it, sorry

Comment: @Dominik AFAIN that's not true, the class (s)he has in the VM doesn't inherit from `Control`, it's a "normal" class. In the `Control` (s)he is defining an `IEnumerable` of that class.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez You aren't supposed to do ANYTHING with Controls in MVVM in your Viewmodels. You shouldn't have a single reference to anything that has to do with WPF itsself.

Comment: @Dominik who said (s)he is doing anything with `Control` in the VM ? (S)He just has a `public  ObservableCollection<RfidTag> RfidTagList; ` in the VM which is bound to the `Control`. (S)He is doing NOTHING with the `Control` in the VM.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez alright, then I missunderstood the current state. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I will try to go all over your question (if I miss something let me know) but first you should explain the purpose of binding a `Collection` in a control as a DP.

> is it a good practice to expose a VM-related class to a Control class?

`RfidTag`, I suppose, is a `Model`. What you are really doing here is binding a `Model` in your control which go against the `MVVM` pattern. You should think about the next question... Do you really need all your `RfidTag` to be shown in the `View` ? If you need to show a name, an ID... you could just create an `IEnumerable<string>` as DP (which is correct) and then in your `VM` instead of an `ObservableCollection<RfidTag>` you would have an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Some simple theory. In `MVVM`, `VM` adapts the `Model` to the `View`. So your `VM` should have everything that will be shown in your `View`.

> is the VM source file a good place for the RfidTag class?

`RfidTag` is a `Model` so there's no better place for it :)

Comment: Ty Juan Carlos Rodriguez. I've edited my question to clarify my problem